# Gradle dependencies with file directories

Tags: dependencies, gradle

I'm writing an EJB jar module for a jboss ear application. I'm using gradle and I don't want to try to declare all of the different dependencies that the jar would rely on at runtime from JBoss. Is there a way to declare dependencies on all files within a directory tree.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the dependencies section of your `build.gradle` file you can use a [`FileTree`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileTree.html) reference. For example:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "${jbossDir}/client", includes: ['*.jar'])
}
```

This will include all of the JAR files in the JBoss / client directory as compile-time dependencies.

Comment: NOTE: these dependencies do not show up when you run the gradle dependencies task!  From the doc: "File dependencies are not included in the published dependency descriptor for your project. However, file dependencies are included in transitive project dependencies within the same build."

Comment: Is fileTree works for all subdirectories in the libs folder. Example few jars inside the libs/sping/spring.jar, in this case does it include the spring .jar also?

Comment: includes: ['/**/*.jar'] would catch all sub directories jar files under some root dir