# How to add a Netbeans project as a dependency to a Gradle project?

Tags: netbeans, ant, gradle

I am new to gradle and most of my existing projects are in ant (netbeans projects).

Do I have to create gradle project for each of those projects that I would want to reuse?

Can I straightaway declare existing netbeans projects as dependencies in my gradle project? If yes, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is to add a dependency on files produced by Ant build (they are usually in `build/dist`). This would be similar to [Gradle dependencies with file directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638555/gradle-dependencies-with-file-directories)

Better solution is to start using repository manager: Ivy, Artifactory, Nexus. Then update your NetBeans projects to publish built artifacts into this repository and your Gradle projects can easily refer to them. Check for more details in http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html