# Ant to Gradle, Problem with javaCompile task

Tags: java, gradle, ant

I have the following ant task:

```
<javac 
  srcdir="${mypackage.code.src.java}"
    source="1.8"
  target="1.8" 
  destdir="${mypackage.build.output.}"     
  deprecation="on" 
  debug="true" 
  >

  <classpath path="${jboss.common.lib.}/hibernate-annotations-3.5.0-Final.jar" />
  <classpath path="${jboss.common.lib.}/jboss-ejb3-common.jar" />
  <classpath path="${jboss.common.lib.}/scheduler-plugin.jar" />
  <classpath path="${jboss.common.lib.}/servlet-api.jar" />

  <classpath>
    <path>
      <fileset dir="${myotherpackage.lib.thirdparty.}">
        <include name="jboss-5.1.0.GA/ejb3-persistence.jar" />
        <include name="jboss-5.1.0.GA/hibernate-core-4.2.1.final.jar"/>
        <include name="jboss-5.1.0.GA/jboss-javaee.jar" />   
        <include name="jboss-5.1.0.GA/jboss-j2se.jar"/>
        <include name="jboss-5.1.0.GA/jsp-api.jar"/>
      </fileset>
      <fileset dir="${jboss.server.myotherpackage.lib.}">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
      </fileset>
      <fileset dir="${jboss.server.myotherpackageear.}" >
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
      </fileset>
      <fileset dir="${mypackage.code.src.www}/WEB-INF/lib" >
        <include name="**/*.*" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
  </classpath>
</javac>
```

I'm trying to convert it to a gradle, so far I have the following task:

```
task doCompile(type: JavaCompile) {
    classpath = sourceSets.mySourceSet.output
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    destinationDir = file("$mypackage_build_output")
    source = file("$mypackage_code_src_java")
}
```

Also have my sourceset defined as follows:

```
sourceSets {
    jt3SourceSet {
        java {
            compileClasspath += files("${jboss_common_lib}/hibernate-annotations-3.5.0-Final.jar")
            compileClasspath += files("${jboss_common_lib}/jboss-ejb3-common.jar")
            compileClasspath += files("${jboss_common_lib}/scheduler-plugin.jar")
            compileClasspath += files("${jboss_common_lib}/servlet-api.jar")
            compileClasspath += files("${myotherpackage_lib_thirdparty}/jboss-5.1.0.GA/hibernate-core-4.2.1.final.jar")
            compileClasspath += files("${myotherpackage_lib_thirdparty}/jboss-5.1.0.GA/ejb3-persistence.jar")
            compileClasspath += files("${myotherpackage_lib_thirdparty}/jboss-5.1.0.GA/jboss-javaee.jar")
            compileClasspath += files("${myotherpackage_lib_thirdparty}/jboss-5.1.0.GA/jboss-j2se.jar")
            compileClasspath += files("${myotherpackage_lib_thirdparty}/jboss-5.1.0.GA/jsp-api.jar")
            compileClasspath += fileTree(dir: "${jboss_common_lib}", include: ['*.jar'])
            compileClasspath += fileTree(dir: "${jboss_server_mypackage2ear}", include: ['*.jar'])
            compileClasspath += fileTree(dir: "${mypackage_code_src_www}/WEB-INF/lib", include: ['*.*'])
        }
    }
}
```

In the ant compilation it works great, but on gradle it doesnt recognize any of the dependencies declared on the sourceSet.
Also tried adding the dependency on my dependencies{} tag, but it still doesn't work.
Searched everywhere and can't find a solution

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the provided compile task from the [Java](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) plugin?

Comment: @FranciscoMateo I have to do more tasks besides the compilation, but if I can use the compilation task and also do extra stuff after that, I could totally use it. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do extra stuff either before or after the built-in Java compile tasks. From the looks of it, are all of those jars local or can they be retrieved from an online repository like Maven Central?

Comment: @FranciscoMateo all those jars are local, a couple of them are libraries like hibernate, that can be retrieved from maven central, but I have very old libraries included there too

Comment: @jmacboy Can you specify your version of gradle are you using ? thanks

Comment: @bdzzaid Gradle 6.3

Comment: For the local jars you can declare the dependencies as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11638556/611819

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
task doCompile(type: JavaCompile) {
    classpath = sources //a file collection specifying a list of sources
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    destinationDir = file("$mypackage_build_output")
    source = file("$mypackage_code_src_java")
}
```

also deleted the sourceSet, didn't need it anymore.
You can acomplish this with the java plugin, but I needed to do more than compiling, so sticked with to the javacompile task.